Enum in switch pattern causes wrong case to be used
Running in Java 21, the following code works, printing "D2" as I would expect:
public class EnumSandboxTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestEnum test = TestEnum.D; 
        String par = "9999";
        switch (test)
        {
            case D: 
                System.out.println(par.length() < 5 ? "D2" : "D");
                break;
            case E: 
                System.out.println(par.length() < 4 ? "E2" : "E");
                break;
            default: System.out.println("EMPTY (DEFAULT)");
        };
    }   
    private enum TestEnum
    {
        D,E;
    }
}

However, if I change the switch statements to use expressions and pattern matching:
switch (test)
{
    case D -> System.out.println("D");
    case E -> System.out.println("E");
    case TestEnum p when p.equals(TestEnum.D) && par.length() < 5 -> System.out.println("D2");
    case TestEnum p when p.equals(TestEnum.E) && par.length() < 4 -> System.out.println("E2");
    default -> System.out.println("EMPTY (DEFAULT)");
};

Then the output is not "D2". Why does this occur, when par.length() is indeed less than 5 and the TestEnum "test" was set to D?

I cannot reproduce. The code prints "D". Please show a [mcve].

weird, I can reproduce it consistently - I'm using Java 21 if that helps?

regardless, it should print D2

No. "D" is the expected output. Why should it print "D2"?

Same as @Sweeper. This produces "D" on my machine, tested with several JDKs.

par.length() is 4, so  it should pick the "D2" branch

You can confirm here that the output is "D" not "D2" or "E" @simonalexander2005: https://godbolt.org/z/xseePq8o9

@simonalexander2005: "weird, I can reproduce it consistently" - Are you able to do so in an online environment you can share so we can observe it too?

Your case TestEnum p when p.equals(TestEnum.D) && par.length() < 5 -> System.out.println("D2");  will never be reached because case D -> System.out.println("D");  will always match first if test is TestEnum.D.
If you intend to use these "when" clauses, you'll need to remove or reorder the simpler case D and case E statements to be after them.

@SashSinha This is code I've come back to after a while, and I had a note that it would pick the most specific case rather than just the first. Is that not true then?

case D will be tested first...

@simonalexander2005 Your note is incorrect. In a switch statement, the cases are tested in the order presented. First match wins.

In your second switch statement, you are checking first for the case that test matches D, and the arrow means that case should yield/return when it matches. Since you test test to TestEnum.D, it does match, and your program is returning System.out.println("D").
It never cycles down to the other cases. If you test for case TestEnum p when p.equals(TestEnum.D) && par.length() < 5 -> System.out.println("D2") first, above the case D, then you will get D2.

yes, I see that. This is code I've come back to after a while, and I had a note that it would pick the most specific case rather than just the first. Is that not true then?

@simonalexander2005 apparently it is the first... confirm with the Java Language Specification 14.11.1.2. Determining which Switch Label Applies at Run Time: "... If the value is not the null reference, then we determine the first (if any) case label in the switch block that applies ..." (emphasis added)
